# Compiles, and SPI motor driver shields work individually--but not together

Tags: c++, motordriver

I'm using an STM32F767 MCU along with two shields: IHM02A1 dual stepper motor driver. I don't have a debugger yet, but my company is getting one...

In the mean time, I've been un/commenting out parts of Mbed's code. Their Hello World program is available from this website, and it can be used directly in their online IDE by clicking "Import program": https://os.mbed.com/components/X-NUCLEO-IHM02A1/

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "DevSPI.h"
#include "XNucleoIHM02A1.h"

#define MPR_1 4 /* Number of movements per revolution. */

#define STEPS_1 (200 * 128)   /* 1 revolution given a 200 steps motor configured at 1/128 microstep mode. */
#define STEPS_2 (STEPS_1 * 2)

/* Delay in milliseconds. */
#define DELAY_1 1000
#define DELAY_2 2000
#define DELAY_3 3000

/* Motor Control Expansion Board. */
XNucleoIHM02A1 *x_nucleo_ihm02a1;
XNucleoIHM02A1 *x_nucleo_ihm02a1two;

/* Initialization parameters of the motors connected to the expansion board. */
L6470_init_t init[L6470DAISYCHAINSIZE] = {
    /* First Motor. */
    {
        24.0,                          /* Motor supply voltage in V. */
        200,                           /* Min number of steps per revolution for the motor. */
        1.7,                           /* Max motor phase voltage in A. */
        3.06,                          /* Max motor phase voltage in V. */
        300.0,                         /* Motor initial speed [step/s]. */
        500.0,                         /* Motor acceleration [step/s^2] (comment for infinite acceleration mode). */
        500.0,                         /* Motor deceleration [step/s^2] (comment for infinite deceleration mode). */
        992.0,                         /* Motor maximum speed [step/s]. */
        0.0,                           /* Motor minimum speed [step/s]. */
        602.7,                         /* Motor full-step speed threshold [step/s]. */
        3.06,                          /* Holding kval [V]. */
        3.06,                          /* Constant speed kval [V]. */
        3.06,                          /* Acceleration starting kval [V]. */
        3.06,                          /* Deceleration starting kval [V]. */
        61.52,                         /* Intersect speed for bemf compensation curve slope changing [step/s]. */
        392.1569e-6,                   /* Start slope [s/step]. */
        643.1372e-6,                   /* Acceleration final slope [s/step]. */
        643.1372e-6,                   /* Deceleration final slope [s/step]. */
        0,                             /* Thermal compensation factor (range [0, 15]). */
        3.06 * 1000 * 1.10,            /* Ocd threshold [ma] (range [375 ma, 6000 ma]). */
        3.06 * 1000 * 1.00,            /* Stall threshold [ma] (range [31.25 ma, 4000 ma]). */
        StepperMotor::STEP_MODE_1_128, /* Step mode selection. */
        0xFF,                          /* Alarm conditions enable. */
        0x2E88                         /* Ic configuration. */
    },

    /* Second Motor. */
    {
        24.0,                           /* Motor supply voltage in V. */
        200,                           /* Min number of steps per revolution for the motor. */
        1.7,                           /* Max motor phase voltage in A. */
        3.06,                          /* Max motor phase voltage in V. */
        300.0,                         /* Motor initial speed [step/s]. */
        500.0,                         /* Motor acceleration [step/s^2] (comment for infinite acceleration mode). */
        500.0,                         /* Motor deceleration [step/s^2] (comment for infinite deceleration mode). */
        992.0,                         /* Motor maximum speed [step/s]. */
        0.0,                           /* Motor minimum speed [step/s]. */
        602.7,                         /* Motor full-step speed threshold [step/s]. */
        3.06,                          /* Holding kval [V]. */
        3.06,                          /* Constant speed kval [V]. */
        3.06,                          /* Acceleration starting kval [V]. */
        3.06,                          /* Deceleration starting kval [V]. */
        61.52,                         /* Intersect speed for bemf compensation curve slope changing [step/s]. */
        392.1569e-6,                   /* Start slope [s/step]. */
        643.1372e-6,                   /* Acceleration final slope [s/step]. */
        643.1372e-6,                   /* Deceleration final slope [s/step]. */
        0,                             /* Thermal compensation factor (range [0, 15]). */
        3.06 * 1000 * 1.10,            /* Ocd threshold [ma] (range [375 ma, 6000 ma]). */
        3.06 * 1000 * 1.00,            /* Stall threshold [ma] (range [31.25 ma, 4000 ma]). */
        StepperMotor::STEP_MODE_1_128, /* Step mode selection. */
        0xFF,                          /* Alarm conditions enable. */
        0x2E88                         /* Ic configuration. */
    }
};

int main()
{
    /* Initializing SPI bus. */
#ifdef TARGET_STM32F429
    DevSPI dev_spi(D11, D12, D13);

#else
    DevSPI dev_spi(D11, D12, D13);
#endif

    /* Initializing Motor Control Expansion Board. */
    x_nucleo_ihm02a1 =    new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], A4, A5, D4, D2, &dev_spi);
    x_nucleo_ihm02a1two = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], A4, A5, D4, A2, &dev_spi);  

    /* Building a list of motor control components. */
    L6470 **motors = x_nucleo_ihm02a1->get_components();
    L6470 **motorstwo = x_nucleo_ihm02a1two->get_components();

    /* Setting the home position. */
    //motorstwo[1]->set_home();
//    wait_ms(DELAY_1);
    int position = motorstwo[1]->get_position();
    wait_ms(DELAY_1);

//      motors[1]->move(StepperMotor::FWD, STEPS_2);
//      motors[0]->move(StepperMotor::FWD, STEPS_2);    
//    wait_ms(DELAY_2);
      motorstwo[1]->move(StepperMotor::FWD, STEPS_2);
      motorstwo[0]->move(StepperMotor::FWD, STEPS_2);

    position = motorstwo[1]->get_position();
    wait_ms(DELAY_1); 

}
```

That's a minimum reproducible example of the full program. If you want to try it out yourself, simply copy/paste it into main.cpp (in the online IDE noted above).

Everything complies, no warnings. Either of the lines below (with their matching pointers and such) works by moving the motors. I.e., motorstwo[x] and motors[x] both work out on their own. But when both lines are loaded unto the board...nothing works, the motors do not move. The steppers don't even have a very soft sound coming from them.

```
x_nucleo_ihm02a1 =    new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], A4, A5, D4, D2, &dev_spi);
x_nucleo_ihm02a1two = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], A4, A5, D4, A2, &dev_spi);
```

Why can't these two lines be uploaded together? How can this be fixed?

---

### Edit

The class includes two functions for "XNucleoIHM02A1". The one with seven perimeters is the one to dissect...the second last argument sound be changed (ssel:)
[image]

Looking at the Nucleo schematic, you’ll notice L6470_1_SDO (Serial Data Out) is connected to L6470_0_SDI (Serial Data In). This is a daisy chain configuration. Also note how the bridging SB7 leads to the D2 pin on the board.

[image]

Looking at the part datasheet, it will start reading data when /CS is low, and will keep shifting data out until /CS is high.

[image]

By stacking a second board, this configuration results—it’s a combination of both the daisy chain and individually addressed version above:

[image]

---

### Hardware documentation

[Short datasheet](http://mouser.com/ds/2/389/x-nucleo-ihm02a1-954332.pdf). [Long datasheet](http://st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group0/9c/49/e6/da/a3/75/48/b9/DM00237629/files/DM00237629.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00237629.pdf).

Comment: What are `A4`, `A5`, `D4`, `D2`? I am guessing these are pins to which you connect the motor? If that is so, you cannot connect both motors to the same pins at the same time. You need more pins. You also cannot use the same `init[0]` and `init[1]` for both of them.

Comment: @zvone `A4` = `flag_irq`, `A5` = `busy_irq`, `D4` = `standby_reset`, and the only changed pin is for `ssel` (as displayed in the edit above). My understanding is that they're interrupts and flags.

Comment: @zvone So I'm pretty sure that changing them would be pointless.

Comment: The old IHM0**1**A1 single motor driver board does not change any of the pins which I don not quite get:
motor1 = new PowerStep01(D2, D4, D8, D9, D10, dev_spi); // ..............................................................
  motor2 = new PowerStep01(D2, D4, D8, D9, D10, dev_spi); // ..............................................................
  motor3 = new PowerStep01(D2, D4, D8, D9, D10, dev_spi);

Comment: My suspicion is that the API has an unwritten assumption that you're breaking somehow. For example, why would you need to pass in both init structures if you're really only interested in one of the motors?

Out of curiosity, have you tried compiling and running the 3-motor example without any modifications?

Comment: @TriskalJM When it was run with the original program, and the first and second shield had the same zero-ohm configuration (same pins to the Nucleo MCU), the second shield would mirror the first: motor3:motor1 and motor4:motor2. However, each motor needs to run independently. So on the second shield I unsoldered SB23 and soldered SB7: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group0/9c/49/e6/da/a3/75/48/b9/DM00237629/files/DM00237629.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00237629.pdf#page=11 (bottom of page). Second shield did not cause motors 3 nor 4 to move.

Answer (score 3):

You say you have two shields? Each shield having a IHM02A1 driver on it? Please elaborate...

If that is the case, You can use the same SPI bus but you will need a separate chip select line for each shield.

I'm not much of a Arduino user so I'm not to familiar with their drivers. I download the example project and had a quick look:

As for the IHM02A1 class, the constructor looks like this:

```
XNucleoIHM02A1(L6470_init_t *init_0, L6470_init_t *init_1, uint8_t flag_irq, uint8_t busy_irq, uint8_t standby_reset, uint8_t ssel, SPIClass *spi);
```

where the parameters have the following descriptions:

```
/**
 * @brief Constructor.
 * @param init_0        pointer to the initialization structure of the first motor.
 * @param init_1        pointer to the initialization structure of the second motor.
 * @param flag_irq      pin name of the FLAG pin of the component.
 * @param busy_irq      pin name of the BUSY pin of the component.
 * @param standby_reset pin name of the STBY\RST pin of the component.
 * @param ssel          pin name of the SSEL pin of the SPI device to be used for communication.
 * @param spi           SPI device to be used for communication.
 */
```

The 6th parameters is the select pin. This is where you have to specify the select pin for each shield.

You will then need two instances of the class XNucleoIHM02A1, one for each shield. It is NOT an instance per motor. The class already makes provision for two motors.

```
XNucleoIHM02A1 *x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield1; // Class for shield 1
XNucleoIHM02A1 *x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield2; // Class for shield 2

x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield1 = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], FLAG1, BUSY1, STBY_RST1, SS1, &dev_spi);
x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield2 = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], FLAG2, BUSY2, STBY_RST2, SS2, &dev_spi);
```

where SS1 and SS2 are the chip select pins. Note: You will have to fill these with actual pin numbers.

You also have to ensure that the rest of the parameters are defined correctly. You will most probably need separate pins for FLAG, BUSY and STBY/RST for each shield. Therefore I defined the parameters, FLAG1,FLAG2, BUSY1, BUSY2, STBY_RST1, STBY_RST2. Note: You will have to fill these with actual pin numbers.

**Addendum:**

If you need different parameters for each motor, then you will need four different init structures:

```
L6470_init_t init_shield1[L6470DAISYCHAINSIZE] = {...};
L6470_init_t init_shield2[L6470DAISYCHAINSIZE] = {...};

x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield1 = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init_shield1[0], &init_shield1[1], FLAG1, BUSY1, STBY_RST1, SS1, &dev_spi);
x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield2 = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init_shield2[0], &init_shield2[1], FLAG2, BUSY2, STBY_RST2, SS2, &dev_spi);
```

But if all the motors have the same parameters and/or requirements, then you only need one init structure

```
L6470_init_t init[L6470DAISYCHAINSIZE] = {...};

x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield1 = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], FLAG1, BUSY1, STBY_RST1, SS1, &dev_spi);
x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield2 = new XNucleoIHM02A1(&init[0], &init[1], FLAG2, BUSY2, STBY_RST2, SS2, &dev_spi);
```

You will need to call "get_components" for each shield:

```
// For easier reading
#define L6470_S1M1 (0u) // Index of shield1 motor1
#define L6470_S1M2 (1u) // Index of shield1 motor2
#define L6470_S2M1 (0u) // Index of shield2 motor1
#define L6470_S2M2 (1u) // Index of shield2 motor2

L6470 **motors_shield1 = x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield1->get_components();
L6470 **motors_shield2 = x_nucleo_ihm02a1_shield2->get_components();
```

Then you operate on the motors in the following manner:

```
motors_shield1[L6470_S1M1]->set_home(); // Home motor1 on shield1
motors_shield1[L6470_S1M2]->set_home(); // Home motor2 on shield1
motors_shield2[L6470_S2M1]->set_home(); // Home motor1 on shield2
motors_shield2[L6470_S2M2]->set_home(); // Home motor2 on shield2
```

Comment: @AdamUraynar Sorry for the edits, I think it is fine now.

Comment: Each shield runs two motors. I have three motors, so I need to use two IHM02A1 sheilds. I'm using an STM32F767 MCU, not Ardunio.

Comment: @AdamUraynar Sorry about that. I assumed X-Nucleo is Arduino based. But it does not matter. The answer remains the same.

Comment: @AdamUraynar I will add an addendum to my post about "get_components"

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aJYWYX I think it might be working...almost...at least the bottom steppers move without commenting out the code for the second...may have to changing up the physical pinout...

Comment: Issue still isn't resolved. Having the flag, busy and standby/reset pins different has the same result: first instance works, while second does not move motors.

Comment: @adamaero Did you initialise the pins?

Comment: @bluescape Would just adding `DigitalIn flag(A0);` `DigitalIn busy(A1);` `DigitalIn rupt(D1);` solve it? Instead, I tried putting the names in place of the pins and it doesn't compile.

Comment: @adamaero How do you know it is not working? I looked at your code. You step each motor once and then the program exits. Do you know how small is a single step on  a 1.8 degree stepper motor? It is very difficult to visually verify a single step. Put in more steps.

Comment: STEPS_1 is one full revolution. The original program viably moves the motors on one level.